# SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool with "paddleocr"

Tags: python, ssl, paddleocr

I'm actually trying to use "paddleocr" with python

I use a conda environnement

i followed the guide on their github : https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.5/doc/doc_en/quickstart_en.md

But when i try to execute this command :

`(paddle_env) C:\Windows\system32>paddleocr --image_dir "path\image" --use_angle_cls true --lang en --use_gpu false`

i get this error :

```
download https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar to C:\Users\PD/.paddleocr/whl\det\en\en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer\en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\Scripts\paddleocr.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\paddleocr\paddleocr.py", line 571, in main
    engine = PaddleOCR(**(args.__dict__))
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\paddleocr\paddleocr.py", line 420, in __init__
    maybe_download(params.det_model_dir, det_url)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\paddleocr\ppocr\utils\network.py", line 55, in maybe_download
    download_with_progressbar(url, tmp_path)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\paddleocr\ppocr\utils\network.py", line 26, in download_with_progressbar
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PD\anaconda3\envs\paddle_env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

paddleocr version : 2.5.0.3

python version : 3.8.13

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can not access the downlink provided by PaddleOCR, you can try to download the models on its mainpage, set `rec_model_dir` and `det_model_dir` mannually. ([link](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/dygraph/doc/doc_en/whl_en.md))

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1eQr.png)

Answer (score 1):

For paddleocr =2.6.1.3, english, download the files from the
det --> https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar

rec --> https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/PP-OCRv3/english/en_PP-OCRv3_rec_infer.tar

cls --> https://paddleocr.bj.bcebos.com/dygraph_v2.0/ch/ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls_infer.tar

and place them in ".paddleocr" folder in "C:\Users<username><folder_structure>"the folder structure will be the location that you get in the error. For me it was following:

1. .paddleocr\whl\cls\ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls_infer\ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls_infer.tar
2. .paddleocr\whl\det\en\en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer\en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar
3. .paddleocr\whl\rec\en\en_PP-OCRv3_rec_infer\en_PP-OCRv3_rec_infer.tar

and comment the line Lib\site-packages\paddleocr\ppocr\utils\network.py --> #**download_with_progressbar(url, tmp_path)**

This should help you run paddleocr..
Run the following lines to check

from paddleocr import PaddleOCR,draw_ocr

ocr = PaddleOCR(lang='en')

Answer (score 0):

Find site-packages\paddleocr\ppocr\utils\network.py, and modify the following code
def download_with_progressbar(url, save_path).
logger = get_logger()
response = requests.get(url, stream=True,proxies={'https':'http://127.0.0.1:{your_proxy_port}'})